How to forward the ssh from a reverse ssh port to another port?
I have a box which has a VM inside it.
On the box, AllowTcpForwarding no is set and we cannot change this.
I can ssh to the VM directly as:
ssh -p 12022 vm_user@box

The box opens a reverse ssh to a global jump host as:
ssh -R 127.2.1.1:1073:localhost:22 support@global_jump

We can ssh to the box from said global jump host as:
ssh -p 1073 box_user@127.2.1.1

How do I ssh to the VM directly from the global jump host?

Sounds like ssh -J vm_user@127.2.1.1:1073 -p 12022 box_user@localhost should work. Sounds confusing that your box user be called vm_user and your VM user box_user.

Ohh sorry I totally messed that up.
Thing is, I cannot use -J because AllowTcpForwarding is set to no on the box. But the box allows access to the VM via port 12022. Any idea how to ssh to that port from the reverse SSH port?

Try ssh -tp 1073 box_user@127.2.1.1 ssh -p 12022 vm_user@localhost (here swapping the user names after your edit).

If TCP Forwarding is disabled, you could still use nc or something similar to do it yourself, and use ProxyCommand instead of ProxyJump. The ssh_config manpage even gives an example: "For example, the following directive would connect via an HTTP proxy at 192.0.2.0: ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X connect -x 192.0.2.0:8080 %h %p"

@StéphaneChazelas thank you very much, this works!
And muru thank you but it seems like TcpForwarding is still a requirement for proxycommand to work.

No, it's not. It uses stdin/stdout.
